# How to set a method inside one onClick method In ReactJS to finish execution after API call?

Tags: reactjs, axios

I need the background to change colors at the same time the api request is rendered.

I am building a Quote generator. Its a simple one button interface, that once clicked, loads a new quote and changes the background color. I could not find a good way to bind two methods to the same click event, so I have the API call and the color change taking place in the same method. The problem is, the color changes instantly, but the quote takes time to update. I tried calling component DidMount inside the method, but this did not work. I am sure there is an easier approach, I am just missing it.
Here is my code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Button from './Button';
import axios from 'axios'
class QuoteBox extends Component{
   constructor(props){
         super(props)

     this.state = {
        quotes: [],
      colors: ["#16a085", "#27ae60",
             "#2c3e50", "#f39c12",
             "#e74c3c", "#9b59b6",
             "#FB6964", "#342224", 
             "#472E32", "#BDBB99",
             "#77B1A9", "#73A857"]
     }

   }
 componentDidMount(){
   axios.get('http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts? 
   filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]3')
  .then(res=> this.setState({quotes: res.data[0]}))

}

getNext = (ev) =>{
  const {colors} = this.state
  const color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()* colors.length)]
  var newQuote = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50)
  const API_URL = `http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts? 
  filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]${newQuote}`
  ev.preventDefault()
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = color
  axios.get(API_URL)
  .then(res=> this.setState({quotes: res.data[0]}))
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = color
}

render(){
const {content,title} = this.state.quotes
const filteredContent = String(content).replace(/(<\w>)|(<\/\w>)| 
(&#\d{4})|(<\w* \/>)|(\/\w*)/gm, "").replace(/(;)/g,"'")
 console.log(content)

 return(
   <React.Fragment>
      <h2>A little inspiration for the day</h2>
      <div className='outerQuoteBox'>
        <div className='innerQuoteBox'>
            <p>{filteredContent}</p><br/><br/>{title}
        </div>
        <Button getNext={this.getNext} />
    </div>
    </React.Fragment>)
   }
 }


  export default QuoteBox
```

And this is my button component

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react'

 export class Button extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <button onClick={this.props.getNext} className='nextBtn' 
        type='button'>Next<button/>
    )
  }
}  

export default Button
```

I am going to have the font color change with the background as well,and I think I can figure that out, but the color changing so much sooner than the quote changing makes the whole thing look bad. It needs to happen all at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options with your current setup: you can change the background in a callback for your `setState` call, or, you can call it in the same function you're passing to your `then` clause from Axios.

Why? Axios returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) which represents the eventual completion of an asynchronous request (i.e, API call). Your `.then()` call is fired upon a successful (non-error-throwing) completion of the request.

Your code otherwise keeps executing, hence, why your background was changing before your API call completed.

**then()**

```
getNext = (ev) =>{
  const {colors} = this.state
  const color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()* colors.length)]
  var newQuote = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50)
  const API_URL = `http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts? 
  filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]${newQuote}`
  ev.preventDefault()
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = color
  axios.get(API_URL)
  .then(res=> { 
     this.setState({quotes: res.data[0]});
     document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
  });
}
```

**setState callback**

```
getNext = (ev) =>{
  const {colors} = this.state
  const color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()* colors.length)]
  var newQuote = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50)
  const API_URL = `http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts? 
  filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]${newQuote}`
  ev.preventDefault()
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = color
  axios.get(API_URL)
  .then(res=> { 
     this.setState({quotes: res.data[0]}, () => {
       document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
     });
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I havn't learned alot about axios yet, and wasnt aware i could use the promise for anything besides the actual API call. It seems obvious now.